# Induction proof that $4^n > 3^n+2^n$ for $n\ge2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

This is a problem with induction and proofs but I'm not sure how to start with proving this one.

> $$\text{Show that for any $n \geq 2$, $4^n > 3^n+2^n$}$$

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 3 questions during your first few hours on this site. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$4^{n+1} = \underbrace{4 \cdot 4^n > 4 (3^n+2^n)}_{\text{From induction hypothesis}} = \overbrace{4 \cdot 3^n + 4 \cdot 2^n > 3 \cdot 3^n + 2 \cdot 2^n}^{\text{Since }4 > 3 \text{ and }4>2} = 3^{n+1} + 2^{n+1}$$
and you are done.